# How to create a hash with unique results

Tags: java, android, hash, hashcode

I'm trying to design an algorithm that would take a String then convert it into one of four unique results.

Using information about the device, I would like to generate a 16-bit (could be smaller, but would be nice to be at least 16) String.

Any device information would generated one of the four Strings.
The fourth would be any device information + being an emulator.

Is there a good way to do this without compressing the device information down into a number from 0-3 and then expanding it to 16-bit?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is the criteria that the string is placed in one of the 4 categories/results?

Comment: There is no criteria, any String value with just return 1 of the 4 categories. Completely random. As for the 4th, it would be nice to be able to add an extra flag that would just drop it into the 4th slot.

Comment: What's the point of the string-input then if it is completely random? There must be some logic

Comment: The reason is to put them into one of four groups, without having the group's id on the device/code. So nobody can look at the code and change their id to be in another group.

Comment: But does it has to be replicable? Like device A should always land in group 1? Where does this string originally come from? A user input or a database?

Comment: Yes, I don't want the user to be able to just clear the app and get another value. Currently what I'm thinking of is taking the device id, converting that to an int, using that for a seed to somehow create the String. It's a very weird question, I know. But I'm trying to design a way to store the String, without actually having it on the device or in code.

Comment: Why don't you just have a server that does this logic for you? Basically send information to server and get the category back. This way the user wouldn't know how you implemented the algorithm

Comment: That's a very good idea, actually. I'll have to look into it, unsure if I'll have access to a server or not. I may though. It's supposed to be for social interaction, so I was trying to just do it all client side.